# Sharepoint page level security

Tags: sharepoint

Another SharePoint question from myself!

I've created a subsite and from within Sharepoint designer I've created a new aspx page, all nice and simple so far.  I can't seem to find where I can change the security on this new page, only site admins can view the page and everyone else gets access denied.
It doesn't seem to inherit the permissions from the parent and I can't see where to change the security settings!

Please help, I'm sure it's something simple!

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've placed your ASPX file in a 'bad' place. It doesn't sit where the normal security structures for SharePoint work so you won't be able to set its item level permissions (because it is not an 'item'). This is the danger of giving people SharePoint Designer ;)

Personally I think your page belongs in the _layouts folder somewhere since it seems to be an admin page. In there you could simply secure it by a call like:

`SPUtility.EnsureSiteAdminAccess();`

Either you can:

- Put your page in a library so you can set item level permissions to it
- Create a custom control that allows you to call the code above for any page
- Move the page to _layouts

Comment: As you can tell I haven't been using SharePoint very long! Now I know that the 'bad' place isn't good I went with the document library as putting the file in _layouts would not have worked due to the masterpage reference in my page.
Thanks!

Comment: The page in the library works well but now the breadcrumb shows the name of the document library!  We don't want to allow users to be able to click on the library breadcrumb link as it takes them to a list of pages.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: Is it a publishing page in a /Pages library or a normal web part page? The first you can make a new page layout that doesn't have the breadcrumb, the second you should be able to edit with SharePoint Designer to remove the breadcrumb. Might have to put a asp:content tag in to overwrite the breadcrumb in the master.

Answer (score 0):

From SharePoint, you should be able to navigate to where you stored your new aspx page (probably in one of your **Document Libraries**).  From that location you can either change the permission of the Document Library, or manage the permissions of an individual aspx page.

Please note that it is best practice to set permissions at the Site Collection level and allow everything under the Site Collection to inherit permissions.

Comment: My new aspx page isn't in a document library it just sits next to the default.aspx in the root of the subsite.  I've looked at everything under security settings but there doesn't seem anywhere to change the page settings.  It was set to inherit but that didn't work either.  It shouldn't be this hard!